# Testing the same function with different parameters

Tags: python, pytest, python-2.x

I am trying to test a function multiple times using different parameters. The return value should be True.

```
def testConfiguration(small,medium,large):
    ...
    if (everything goes well):
        return True
    else:
        return False

testConfiguration(0,0,1)
testConfiguration(1,2,1)
testConfiguration(1,3,1)
```

What's the best way to go about doing this in pytest? I want to avoid multiple functions acting as assert True wrappers e.g

```
def test_ConfigA():
    assert testConfiguration(0,0,1) == True

def test_ConfigB():
    assert testConfiguration(1,2,1) == True

...
```

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html

Comment: In the future, please try to research questions first, and [treat Stack Overflow as a last resort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). A [straightforward search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pytest+same+test+with+different+parameters) will immediately pull up [relevant documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html).

Comment: Each assert is a "test" and you are free to group them in functions as you see fit. Indeed having a function for every assert might be considered over-the-top, for simple tests I usually start with a single function and split it in more "test cases" only when I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`@pytest.mark.parametrize()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#parametrize-basics)

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("small, medium, large, out", [
    (0,1,1, True),
    (1,2,1, True),
    (1,1,1, False),
])
def test_all(small, medium, large, out):
     assert testConfiguration(small, medium, large) == out
```